# How to move a certain part of a picture box using Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to only move a certain part of my picture box however I could move only that certain part. Currently I can move it from left to right but I only want to move the tip of it only.

```
    private float angle = 0.0f;
    Image image;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) angle += 1;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) angle -= 1;

        int a = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int b = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) a += 5;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) a -= 5;

        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(a, b);

        RotateImage(pictureBox1, image, angle);
    }

    private void RotateImage(PictureBox pb, Image img, float angle)
    {
        //Store our old image so we can delete it
        Image oldImage = pb.Image;
        pb.Image = RotateImage(img, angle);

        if (oldImage != null)
            oldImage.Dispose();
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle)
    {
        return RotateImageFinal(image, new PointF((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2), angle);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImageFinal(Image image, PointF offset, float angle)
    {
        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
        rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);

        //Put the rotation point in the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);

        //rotate the image
        g.RotateTransform(angle);

        //move the image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));

        return rotatedBmp;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //Just to store the address of the 'arrow' image.
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        image = new Bitmap(path + "/img/arrow.bmp");
    }
```

A PS of the object that I want to tilt, I'm interested in fixating the bottom part meanwhile only moving the top
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiJCF.jpg

Comment: Do you mean stretching the picture box, rotating or tilting it?

Comment: For example like an shooter kind i want to leave the bottom fixed meanwhile the picturebox can only move on the tip. So i guess it'll be tilting.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. could you please provide a pic how the result should looks like

Comment: Have you guys ever played the game Bubble Puzzle before? I'm trying to make the turret of it out.[A video and simple explanation of the game.]  (http://escarbandocodigo.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/como-hacer-un-puzzle-bobble-o-bust-a-move-en-xna-parte-2/)

Comment: ahh now i get it actually everything is an object so so you will have multiple picturebox's (one for your Arrow, on foreach bubble and maybe on for your background) and so it will also be rotation for your arrow

Comment: The arrowhead will remain as one picturebox, however the bubbles will be constantly changing if you're firing the bubbles out. I'll try out Ken D methods first hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I was really interested in your question and so I decided to spend some time to search more about image rotation in C#. So here goes the result.

```
    private float angle = 0.0f;
    Image image;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) angle+=1;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) angle-=1;

        int a = ballPB.Location.X;
        int b = ballPB.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) a += 5;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) a -= 5;

        ballPB.Location = new Point(a, b);

        RotateImage(arrowPB, image, angle);
    }

    private void RotateImage(PictureBox pb, Image img, float angle)
    {
        //Store our old image so we can delete it
        Image oldImage = pb.Image;
        pb.Image = RotateImage(img, angle);

        if (oldImage != null)
            oldImage.Dispose();
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle)
    {
        return RotateImageFinal(image, new PointF((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2), angle);
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImageFinal(Image image, PointF offset, float angle)
    {
        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
        rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);

        //Put the rotation point in the center of the image
        g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);

        //rotate the image
        g.RotateTransform(angle);

        //move the image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));

        return rotatedBmp;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //Just to store the address of the 'arrow' image.
        string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        image = new Bitmap(path + "\\img\\arrow.png");
    }
```

The credits for the logic goes to MusicMonkey5555 (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations). You can even download the source code from the link in case the above code isn't really clear. Good luck!

Comment: I don't quite understand this part the "Image" what does it refer to? "Image" = my arrowhead? My arrowhead is also a picturebox as well.

`private void RotateImage(PictureBox pb, Image img, float angle)
    {
        //Store our old image so we can delete it
        Image oldImage = pb.Image;
        pb.Image = RotateImage(img, angle);

        if (oldImage != null)
            oldImage.Dispose();
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle)
    {
        return RotateImageFinal(image, new PointF((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2), angle);
    }`

Comment: The PictureBox may contain the rotated image already. While here 'Image img' refers to the original image of the arrow pointing up as we need the original image every time we want to draw using graphics. Check out my Form_Load to see how image was defined.

Comment: However i keep getting this error of [Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](http://imgur.com/pyMPzSe) any idea what this means?

Comment: @JerryLoh How you initialized your 'img'? Avoid 'img = PictureBox.Image' < as we keep on modifying this. Instead, assign it directly with the .png location. If it doesn't solve your problem, kindly update me with your codes.

Comment: Updated the codes above. However there's the same error there.

Comment: @JerryLoh Weird, the same code doesn't give me any such error. I intentionally made such an error by assigning image = null (like seen here: http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/3393/97408609.jpg). Can you do the same and tell me the value of image when the error  occurs? Just move your cursor towards any variable to see the current value of it. Usually that error occurs when you are trying to access the property of a NULL value.

Comment: Well the value of the image=null. So does that means that it's not able to read my image out?